# computing max of modes

Tags: c++, arrays, mode

I am using the following code to compute the mode

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int prices[]={1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3};

int main()
{
  double currval=prices[0];
  int ctr=1;
  int maxctr=1;
  double modval=prices[0];
  for (int i=1;i<8;i++) {
    if(prices[i]==currval) {
      ++ctr;
    }else {
      if(ctr>maxctr) {
    maxctr=ctr;
    modval=currval;
      }
      currval=prices[i];
      ctr=1;
    }
  }
 std::cout<<"mode is: "<<modval<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but unfortunately, this returns the first mode.

```
mode is: 2
```

I want to continue to pass over the array and capture all the modes in another array, so then I can select the max or min or average of the array of modes. So, in my example, I would have an array with content {2,3}.
any suggestions on how I do that.
thanks!
EDITED:

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int prices[]={1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3};
std::vector<int> result;

int main()
{
  double currval=prices[0];
  int ctr=1;
  int maxctr=1;
  double modval=prices[0];
  for (int i=1;i<8;i++) {
    if(prices[i]==currval) {
      ++ctr;
    }else {
      if(ctr>maxctr) {
    maxctr=ctr;
    result.clear();
    result.push_back(currval);
      } else {
    if (ctr==maxctr) {
      result.push_back(currval);
    }
      }
      currval=prices[i];
      ctr=1;
    }
  }
 if(ctr>maxctr) {
    maxctr=ctr;
    result.clear();
    result.push_back(currval);
      } else {
    if (ctr==maxctr) {
      result.push_back(currval);
    }
      }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your for loop, you'll want to have i<8 instead of i<9. Currently you're trying to access one element past the end. (Also, what is a mode val?).

Comment: You will also want to start at index 0, `for (int i = 0; ...` as you are currently missing the first element. Forget that...missed you were already storing this.

Comment: I thought he started from 1 on purpose (the element 0 is read before the for loop), but I don't know what the code is intended for, so you might be right.

Comment: The title says you want the maximum mode, but your text says you want a list of all the modes. The first step to solving a problem is to state it precisely. Please edit your question to precisely state what you really want to do.

Comment: thanks for your responses and pointing out the correction to i<8. I want to first get an array of the modes, and then have the ability to select the max or the min. So, in my example, I'd first get an array `{2,3}` and then I can easily select the min or the max of that array, hence 2 or 3 respectively, in my example. hope that clarifies what I intend to do. Ideally, I'd have a template mode function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code's part after else was wrong, as it will get executed after both `if` and `else` which is not what wanted.

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int prices[]={1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ctr=1;
    int maxctr=1;
    vector<int> allModes;
    int max, min;

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {

        if(prices[i+1]==prices[i]) {
            ++ctr;
        }
        else {
            if(ctr == maxctr) {
                allModes.push_back(prices[i]);  //if it is same as previous mode add it to vector
                //max = prices[i];
            }
            if(ctr > maxctr) {
                allModes.clear();           //if it is greater than previous mode then previous number is not a mode now
                                            //so clear old vector
                allModes.push_back(prices[i]);  
                maxctr = ctr;
                //max = prices[i];
                //min = prices[i];
            }
            ctr=1;
        }
    }


    std::cout<<"Mode: ";
    for (  vector<int>::iterator it=allModes.begin() ; it < allModes.end(); ++it ) {
        std::cout<< " " << *it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming array is in ascending order.

But if you want to store min or max or avg you can do this without using vector.

1. For min while transverse don't change mode if it has same count as old one
2. For max you will assign new value for same count
3. For avg, just add all numbers but keep track of how many number added. then at end of loop just take `avg = sum / no. of element`

So in all three cases, vector isn't required.

Comment: I am looking for the min or max of the modes only, not the entire array

Comment: @itcplpl That what I am saying, where you add mode to list also set new max or new min (if count is greater). So at the end of loop you will get min or max of modes

Comment: this is what your code results in, assuming myvector is allModes...the output is: `<Mode:  13853996`

Comment: @itcplpl Sorry forgot to change index to 0. Now it is working correctly for your test case. Also added code for min and max in comment. Avg. you can also be calculated with slight modification.

Answer (score 1):

you need a vector like:
`vector<int>result`

and if you found a counter larger than maxctr:

```
if (ctr > maxctr) {
    maxctr = ctr;
    result.clear();
    result.push_back(currval);
}
```

and if it's equal:

```
if (ctr == maxctr) {
    result.push_back(currval);
}
```

Note that you have to run this part after you count each number:

```
if (price[i] != currval) {
  if (ctr > maxctr) ...
  currval = price[i];
  ctr = 1;
```

}

And after the for loop

```
for (i = 1; ...) { ...}
if (ctr > maxctr) ...
```